Selenium proxy connection issue
I have been trying to connect to proxy for the past few times using proxy please help
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

#################
proxy = "219.65.73.81:80"


opt=Options()

opt.add_argument(f"--proxy-server={proxy}")

driver= webdriver.Chrome(opt)
driver.get('https://whatismyipaddress.com/')

time.sleep(30)

The tab is showing...
This page isn’t working
whatismyipaddress.com didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
How to solve this issue??

What is the error message?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
